# How many shots do temple have in Sky Temple?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

In late game on Sky Temple you can kill the guardians of the Temples pretty fast, this is offcorse the safest approach, but will it affect the damage the Temple to the enemy base?

Will the Temple do the same damage to the enemy base if you kill the guardians as fast as possible or if you keep one alive until its final barrage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Killing the guardians has no effect on temple damage. When the temple is active, you can see the amount of bullets it still has at the top of the tall building. The temple fires every second~ish until all the yellow dots (ammo) are depleted. Then it prepares for a final burst of 5 shots. When the temple is done firing it's regular bullets, you can just leave and it will fire the last five by itself.

You can keep the guardians alive if you want (sometimes useful to keep enemies away with the big guardian's knockback) or you can kill them immediately, it has no effect on the temple's mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

According to [heroesfire](http://www.heroesfire.com/hots/guide/map-timings-2508), the temples fire a total of 45 shots per activation:

> Each temple has a total of 45 shots.

Killing the guardians [presently] has no effect on this.

Answer (score 2):

### Phases

Each Temple has two phases.

#### Phase One

In the first phase, upon activation, a large Guardian will spawn and start a timer.  Players must remain on the Temple to keep the Temple under their control and to have the timer continue. The timer will only run if a Team has control of the Temple.  If at any time your team steps off of the Temple and the Temple becomes neutral, the timer stops.  If you or the Enemy Team then grab the Temple, the timer resumes.  At two different times for the timer, two smaller Guardians will spawn, making a total of one large Guardian and four small Guardians.  The timer will not allow all five Guardians to spawn too quickly, even if your team completely destroys a set of Guardians.

During this phase, you can think of the Temple as a balance;  whichever team has more players on it, will out-weight the other team, which means they will gain control of the Temple.

This phase lasts ~45 seconds.

#### Phase Two

Once the first phase is complete, which is *not* defined by the death of the Guardians, but instead the completion of the timer, the second phase will begin.  At this time, the Temple will charge up and you will see how many shots it has (currently five shots).  Once the Temple is controlled by a Team, the Temple cannot switch sides.  It is important to note that an Enemy Team can come in and grab the temple just before the first phase ends and steal all of your hard work.

**To get from phase one to phase two, you must wait for the timer to complete.  Guardians and their death have no impact on the timer's speed, nor do they increase the number of shots nor power of shots.  As the timer continues, the Temple will fire for whichever team has control of it at that time.**

### Placement

The top and middle Temple will always activate for the first round.  The very bottom Temple will activate for the second round.  Temple activation is random from this point further.

After the first two rounds, one, two or three Temples may activate per round.

### Timing

You are first warned that Temples are activating at 1:15, with a 15 second warning which means it becomes active at 1:30.

*If anybody is aware of additional timing info, please place it here, or comment.*

Answer (score 0):

The shots have a limit, like the towers they have a bullet count. When the bullet count is done then it's done. Doesn't matter if you kill them fast or not.

Just make sure you have a claim to the territory